# Cmus can’t see mp3 files

Tags: mp3, cmus

I’m running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and i3-gaps on an old MacBook Pro. I’ve been trying to get Cmus working for a little while, I have moved one of my mp3 files to my downloads to try and get it playing. It shows up in terminal and in files, but on cmus it doesn’t show up at all in Browser or if I :add to the file. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What does the command `cmus --plugins` show?

Comment: Lists a ton of input plugins and 4 output plugins, the only one that supports mp3 file type is ffmpeg at the bottom of the list.

Comment: On a default install (which I have just done) there should be a set of priorities for mp3 playback and if you look at the top `mad` has a priority of 55 for mp3 playback while `ffmpeg` has a priority of 30. Can you see this on your system?

Comment: Yeah mad has 55, ffmpeg has 30, and all others have 50.

Comment: Perhaps try to reinstall the 2 possible offenders: `sudo apt-get install libmad0 cmus-plugin-ffmpeg` and try again...

Comment: Tried removing and reinstalling both, still can’t see them in browser or in :add.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas sorry, on a new install this all just works on my system....

Comment: How did you install it? (Git clone or apt-get) I’ve been doing it from apt so maybe that’s it?

Comment: I simply used `sudo apt-get install cmus`

Comment: Oh, I’m not sure then :\